# Trouble selecting multiple IDs using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to close a popup window either by clicking on #profile-container or  #profile-close. For some reason I cannot apply both to this function either by combining the ID's or writing each separately. If I comment out #profile-container, #profile-close works otherwise only the #profile-container works. I also tried combining both ID's in one command, but again only the #profile-container.

Separately:

```
$("#profile-close").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $("#profile-container").toggleClass("active");
    $(".wrapper").toggleClass("bg-blur");
});

$("#profile-container").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $("#profile-container").toggleClass("active");
    $(".wrapper").toggleClass("bg-blur");
});
```

Both Together:

```
$("#profile-container, #profile-close").each(function(){ 
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
        $("#profile-container").toggleClass("active");
        $(".wrapper").toggleClass("bg-blur")             
    }); 
});
```

```
<div id="profile-container">
      <div id="profile">

        <div id="profile-close">close</div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mt-4">
            <div id="profile-image">
              <img src="./media/team-one.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="mt-2">
              <div id="profile-name">Stanley</div>
              <div id="profile-title">Founder & CEO</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-4">
            <div id="profile-data">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate consequatur fuga fugiat dolore doloribus quasi ducimus ea aperiam minima illum!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

```
#profile-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 700px;
  width: 900px;
  background: var(--bg-dark);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  padding-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: 0.7s;
}

#profile-close {
  color: var(--nav-text);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#profile-container.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.95;
  z-index: 3;
}

.wrapper {
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.bg-blur {
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant CSS, please? It might be a problem with CSS specificity, and it would be easier to figure out either way.

Comment: CSS added @Skylar

Comment: What does the `on` class do?

Comment: I don't know what the **on** class was for. I'm new to jQuery and I found an example that fit what I wanted to do so I used it and changed the classes. I couldn't find what the **on** class was for them either so I left it just in case it was a jQuery thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple selectors simply aren't necessary. If someone clicks the close button, the event will propagate to the profile container, which will the trigger the event handler.

This code should work:

```js
$("#profile-container").click(function() {
  // $('   ?   ').toggleClass('on');
  // (The "on" class is not described. I don't know how it should work.)
  $("#profile-container").toggleClass("active");
  $(".wrapper").toggleClass("bg-blur");
});
```

Try it out in the snippet below.

```js
$("#profile-container").click(function() {
  // $("#profile-container").toggleClass('on');
  $("#profile-container").toggleClass("active");
  $(".wrapper").toggleClass("bg-blur");
});
```

```css
#profile-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  background: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  padding-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: 0.7s;
  color: white;
}

#profile-close {
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#profile-container.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.95;
  z-index: 3;
}

.wrapper {
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.bg-blur {
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-container" class="active">
  <div id="profile">

    <div id="profile-close">close</div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mt-4">
        <div id="profile-image">
          <img src="./media/team-one.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2">
          <div id="profile-name">Stanley</div>
          <div id="profile-title">Founder &amp; CEO</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 mt-4">
        <div id="profile-data">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate consequatur fuga fugiat dolore doloribus quasi ducimus ea aperiam minima illum!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. When I used the code for both IDs the 'close' button did not work, but when I used on the code for the container I never thought to still try the 'code' button.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ids you can use it. But also you have to use

`$(this).toggleClass("active");` rather than `$("#profile-container").toggleClass("active");`

Because you are doing toggling classes. so your code was only toggle class `#profile-container` not on `#profile-close` so you needs to use `$(this)`

Try it, may help you.

```js
$(document).on('click','#profile-container,#profile-close',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".wrapper").toggleClass("bg-blur");
});
```

```css
#profile-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: var(--bg-dark);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  padding-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: 0.7s;
  background: red;
  
}

#profile-close {
  color: var(--nav-text);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: -1;
}

#profile-container.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.95;
  z-index: 3;
}

.wrapper {
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.bg-blur {
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="profile-container" class="active">
      <div id="profile">

        <div id="profile-close">close</div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mt-4">
            <div id="profile-image">
              <img src="./media/team-one.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="mt-2">
              <div id="profile-name">Stanley</div>
              <div id="profile-title">Founder & CEO</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mt-4">
            <div id="profile-data">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate consequatur fuga fugiat dolore doloribus quasi ducimus ea aperiam minima illum!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```